# This inheritance program when executed gives output '2'. How?

Tags: java

```
class A { }

class B extends A { }

class C extends B { }

public class MainClass  {

    static void overloadedMethod(A a) {
        System.out.println("1");
    }

    static void overloadedMethod(B b) {
        System.out.println("2");
    }

    static void overloadedMethod(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("3");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C();
        overloadedMethod(c);
    }
}
```

This inheritance program when executed gives output `2`. How?

Comment: Because inheritance is a "is-a" relationship? An object of class `C` is also an object of class `B` (and `A` but `B` is closer). What else did you expect?

Comment: This kind of overloading is a recipe for unpredictable and unreadable code and should be avoided. From `Effective Java`: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31551&seqNum=4

Answer (score 1):

Well, an instance of class `C` can be passed to any of these three `overloadedMethod` methods, so the compiler selects the method whose arguments have the most specific type - `static void overloadedMethod(B b)` - since `B` is a sub-class of `A`, which is a sub-class of `Object`, and therefore `B` is more specific than both `A` and `Object`.

Comment: This should point that with this declaration `Object o = new C();`, it will have an "unexpected" result.

Comment: @AxelH That depends on what you consider to be "unexpected".

Comment: Well, knowing that this is made a compile time, it is the expected result for me. But it is always a bit strange for newbie, that's why I said "unexpected"  and not unexpected ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you know that here `C` class is a child class of `B` and `B` is a child class of `A`. Class `A` is also a child class of `Object` class(you cannot see it because it is determined at compile time).

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html):

> Excepting Object, which has no superclass, every class has one and
>   only one direct superclass (single inheritance). In the absence of any
>   other explicit superclass, every class is implicitly a subclass of
>   Object.
>
> Classes can be derived from classes that are derived from classes that
>   are derived from classes, and so on, and ultimately derived from the
>   topmost class, Object. Such a class is said to be descended from all
>   the classes in the inheritance chain stretching back to Object.

So, what is the closest and most suitable class for class `C`.

```
C c = new C();
overloadedMethod(c);
```

It's parent class `B` right!. When you overload the method compiler will choose the:

```
static void overloadedMethod(B b) {
    System.out.println("2");
}
```

Since, `Object` class in the top of class heirarchy and class `A` is the grand parent of `C`.